# Change the last-updated behaviour of the site when tags are edited

Tags: discussion

It's not a huge deal, but I think it would be an improvement if the site didn't consider that questions had been updated as a result of someone editing the tags.

Sometimes you visit the site and think wow - *loads of questions I'm interested in have all come back onto the first page, that's great!* - then you look a little closer and realise that someone has been diligently retagging them; the question and answer content is actually the same as it was a few days ago.

I know it only seems like a minor thing, but I just don't feel that retagging a question should cause it to appear as if it's had another answer or a significant edit.

Please don't misunderstand - I hugely approve of tagging and especially of those hardy souls who spend their valuable time correctly tags, it's appreciated. I'm just not sure that adding or editing a tag should alter the 'last updated' status of a question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for spamming the home page with retagging.

I highly approve this and I hope it isn't a hard-coded mechanism of stackexchange.

If this is the case, you should post your proposal on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm glad you retag the questions, @Studer - it's a worthwhile cause and as soon as I get the rep to do it I'll gladly step-in where I see a need. I just wish it didn't affect the timestamps (or whatever) on the questions themselves. I'll have a look at the meta for StackOverflow (where I've spent most of my time) and see if this situation has been mentioned before - I'm sure it will have already been discussed. :-)

Comment: @robsoft - I hope you'll find an answer, because that would be really useful.

Comment: FWIW, Moderators can retag without causing the timestamps to change.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose for bumping to the home page is to avoid tag abuse. Since there are badges and a complete tag wiki system involved, bumping it prevents someone from creating arbitrary tags.

Moderators can do a mass re-tag which will not bump questions, which is generally the process should there be more then a certain number of tags that need to be changed.